# Bootstrap Dropdown not working in my angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using bootstrap dropdown in my angularjs application. But unable to get the dropdown. Here is my code:

```
     <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-default">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-primary">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-success">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-info">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-warning">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-danger">Alert Badge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">View All</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

I tried removing **href="javascript:void(0)"** and instead I used **data-target**.
I am not getting the dropdown.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `bootstrap.js` and 'jquery'? Please add these files bottom of your page and reload the page.

Comment: It's not the problem with bootstrap.js or jQuery. I checked it.